# ¿Cómo separar entidades de la capa de datos? Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-6

Hola estoy viendo de implementar un software en 3 capas usando EF, me surge la duda como hago para separar las entidades de la capa de datos para ponerlas en la capa de negocio. En muchos lados leí que lo que hacen es "cortar" el archivo .tt y ponerlo dentro de la capa negocio.. pero que pasa cuando actualizo el modelo? tengo que cortar y pegar denuevo? o se actualiza directamente ?? es buena práctica eso?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que lenguaje usas para programar ?

Comment: @EmersonRios utilizo c# con visual studio y sql

Comment: Como estructura del proyecto luce bien, pero las razones de porque se hace esto nos cambian al tema de programación orientada a objetos, probablemente quieras investigar un poco sobre la implementacion de patrones como repository para abstraer la lógica de acceso a datos https://www.infoworld.com/article/3107186/how-to-implement-the-repository-design-pattern-in-c.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo hago asi :

1. agrega a tu solución un un proyecto de libraría de clases, yo uso la notación siguiente
   PREFIJO DEL PROYECTO + "DAL", osea, que si el modelo que crearas en EntityFramework corresponde a un modelo de clientes tu proyecto se llamara CLI_DAL (por ejemplo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Agregas un nuevo elemento de tipo ADO.NET Entity Data Model de la sección "data" de elementos de visual estudio c#, y le colocas el prefijo del projecto algo asi como CLI_Model

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Elijes EF designer desde base de datos y configuras la conexion y elijes las tablas que importaras.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este paso te creara un proyecto que incluye el modelo edmx algo parecido a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4. Seguidamente agrega otro proyecto de librería de clases como el el del paso 1, solo que esta vez nombralo así (al menos es la manera que yo utilizo) CLI_Entities
5. Ahora agrega un nuevo elemento de la seccion data de elementos de visual studio c#, solo que ahora elije EF 6.xDbContexxt Generator

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

6. Esto te generar este error indicandorte que debes actualizar el archivo CLI_model.tt con la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo edmx

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debes corregirlo y te deberia quedar asi :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

7. Ahora ya tienes un modelo edmx y un modelo de Entidades listo para trabajar
8. Ahora agrega otro proyecto de librería de clases esta vez con el prefijo CLI_BLL 
   (Clientes Bussiness logic layer).
9. Ahora solo te queda crear tus clases manejadoras de tus entidades.

Comment: plantié eso yo, hice un capa para entidades y la otra para los datos, luego separé el archivo .tt  y lo adjunté en la capa entidades. ahora me surge la duda de: si es necesario crear las clases entidades? no puedo trabajar directamente con las clases entidades que me genera EF, luego yo creo en la capa de negocios las clases para tener control y acceder a la capa de datos , es correcto? o es indispensable crear las clases en la capa entidades?

Comment: Primero nunca deberias cortar y pegar los archivos generados en cada proyecto, debes hacerlo como te plantee, esto que hiciste "luego separé el archivo .tt y lo adjunté en la capa entidades." no esta bien, no es una buena practica. Lo de  es indispensable o no... No es realmente que sea indispensable, se hace por orden. Algo que obvie decirte es que debes borrar el modelo tt del modelo edmx, y debes borrar el modelo`context del proyecto entities.

Comment: Entonces es mas por orden ademas que eso te permite hacer modificaciones en el modelo de entidades sin que impacte en la manera en que se comporta entity framework a la hora de devolverte datos desde tu base de datos, ademas esto también te permite crear un modelo de clases donde separes la lógica de acceso a datos, de la lógica de comportamiento de las entidades, a su vez separado de la capa de lógica de negocio.

Comment: Esto te permite crear menos acoplamiento en tus proyectos a la hora de reutilizar tus modelo de clases.

Comment: claro como lo entiendo lo veia como muy repetitivo crear una clase entidad por encima de las que ya me creaba EF, ahora adjunto unas imagenes de como tengo las capas y clases

Comment: ahi edité el post con las imagenes del modelo de capas

Comment: otra duda que tengo es, si yo hago mis propias clases entidades despues cuando actualizo el modelo de EF desde la BD, tengo que actualizar manualmente todas mis clases entidades?? cosa que si trabajo directamente con el EF no tendria que hacer

Comment: No, existe "Ejecutar Herramienta Personalizada" esta te actualiza el modelo de clases, la encuentras dando click derecho en el archivo .tt, para que funciones debes configurar la ruta en el archivo edmx

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94318/discussion-between-fer-and-emerson-rios).